# Flutter dropdown list from .json

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter development.

I want to retrieve data from a .json file (list of universities), and allow user to type the first letters so they can find their universities in the flutter drop down options.

The data I want to retrieve from the .json file is 'nom_court'.

My initial code is a textfield, and it's working perfectly :

```
  TextFormField buildUniFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.uni,
      onSaved: (newValue) => uni = newValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: kEmailNullError);
        } else if (emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          removeError(error: kInvalidEmailError);
        }
        return null;
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: kEmailNullError);
          return "";
        } else if (!emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          addError(error: kInvalidEmailError);
          return "";
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "University",
        hintText: "Enter your university name",
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: CustomSurffixIcon(svgIcon: "assets/icons/uni.svg"),
```

I am now trying to use a dropdownlist, using the .json file, and put this directly in the widget code :

```
         @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          buildEmailFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(30)),
          buildUniFormField(),
          DropdownButton<String>(
              items:list.map((Map val){
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                 value: val["Uniname"],
                 child: new Text(val["nom_court"]),
          );).toList(),},
```

It's not working, I have an error on the 'Dropdown Button, saying '**The parameter Onchanged isn't defined**'

Thanks :)

Comment: does it work? if not, what's the exact problem?

Comment: Hello @Sara, I'd ask you to run this code and if you face any issues, then create a question.

Comment: @mfkw1 Hi, I added more details on my problem.. thank you!

Comment: Please include the exact error message. You should always select revelant information and try to state your problem as clearly as possible.

Comment: Done, I hope it's better. I'm sorry, it's the first time I post.

Answer (score 0):

use autocomplete_textfield: ^1.6.4 package it would better option than a dropdown widget
https://medium.com/flutter-community/implementing-auto-complete-search-list-a8dd192bd5f6

Comment: Hi, my code isn't working despite having no errors. Could you help?

Comment: follow the steps given in the link, you can make it work properly.

Comment: I tried, it's not showing anything... And no errors :/ I made another post here, maybe you can see why : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65741190/no-errors-for-dropdown-list-but-still-not-working-on-flutter?noredirect=1#comment116237887_65741190

Comment: No, still haven't figured it out

Answer (score 0):

So, it's just like your error message says, you haven't provided `onChanged` parameter to your `DropdownButton`.

You should create a state for current dropdown value and `setState` it in `onChanged` callback () for current dropdown value and `setState` it in `onChanged` callback:

```dart
class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  String dropdownValue = // here specify the initial value for DropdownButton

  Widget build(...) {
    //...
    DropdownButton(
      value: dropdownValue,
      onChanged: (value) => setState(() => dropdownValue = value),
      items: list.map(...),
    ),
  }
}
```

I assume you are already using StatefulWidget, if not please read the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive)

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I've used the Autocomplete text field and it's not showing at all, despite having no errors... i'll try your method !