# No errors for dropdown list, but still not working on Flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

Here's my code for my sign in page on Flutter. I have no errors, but it's still not showing the dropdown list, does anyone know why?
I've used the auto-complete search method.

Here's what I've done so far :
Edited the pubspec.yaml
Imported the unilist.json (which I'm using)
Created a Plain Old Dart Object to represent json structure
And finally, edited my sign in dart file.

I'm having no errors so far, so I believe I'm missing something..

Thanks,

```
import 'package:autocomplete_textfield/autocomplete_textfield.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shop_app/components/custom_surfix_icon.dart';
import 'package:shop_app/components/default_button.dart';
import 'package:shop_app/components/form_error.dart';
import 'package:shop_app/screens/complete_profile/complete_profile_screen.dart';
import 'package:shop_app/screens/sign_up/components/unilist.dart';

import '../../../constants.dart';
import '../../../size_config.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();

class UniViewModel {
  static List<UniName> uni;

  static Future loadUni() async {
    try {
      uni = new List<UniName>();
      String jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/unilist.json');
      Map parsedJson = json.decode(jsonString);
      var categoryJson = parsedJson['uni'] as List;
      for (int i = 0; i < categoryJson.length; i++) {
        uni.add(new UniName.fromJson(categoryJson[i]));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}

  class SignUpForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpFormState createState() => _SignUpFormState();
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: AutoComplete(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AutoComplete extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AutoCompleteState createState() => new _AutoCompleteState();
}

class _AutoCompleteState extends State<AutoComplete> {
  GlobalKey<AutoCompleteTextFieldState<UniName>> key = new GlobalKey();

  AutoCompleteTextField searchTextField;

  TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();

  _AutoCompleteState();

  void _loadData() async {
    await UniViewModel.loadUni();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Auto Complete List Demo'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
            child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
              new Column(children: <Widget>[
                searchTextField = AutoCompleteTextField<UniName>(
                    style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0),
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        suffixIcon: Container(
                          width: 85.0,
                          height: 60.0,
                        ),
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 30.0, 10.0, 20.0),
                        filled: true,
                        hintText: 'Search Uni Name',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                    itemSubmitted: (item) {
                      setState(() => searchTextField.textField.controller.text =
                          item.nom_court);
                    },
                    clearOnSubmit: false,
                    key: key,
                    suggestions: UniViewModel.uni,
                    itemBuilder: (context, item) {
                      return Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(item.nom_court,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16.0
                            ),),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                          ),
                          Text(item.localisation,
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                    itemSorter: (a, b) {
                      return a.nom_court.compareTo(b.nom_court);
                    },
                    itemFilter: (item, query) {
                      return item.nom_court
                          .toLowerCase()
                          .startsWith(query.toLowerCase());
                    }),
              ]),
            ])));
  }
}


class _SignUpFormState extends State<SignUpForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String email;
  String password;
  String uni;
  String conform_password;
  bool remember = false;
  final List<String> errors = [];

  void addError({String error}) {
    if (!errors.contains(error))
      setState(() {
        errors.add(error);
      });
  }

  void removeError({String error}) {
    if (errors.contains(error))
      setState(() {
        errors.remove(error);
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          buildEmailFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(30)),
          FormError(errors: errors),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(40)),
          DefaultButton(
            text: "Continuer",
            press: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                _formKey.currentState.save();
                // if all are valid then go to success screen
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, CompleteProfileScreen.routeName);
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildConformPassFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      obscureText: true,
      onSaved: (newValue) => conform_password = newValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: kPassNullError);
        } else if (value.isNotEmpty && password == conform_password) {
          removeError(error: kMatchPassError);
        }
        conform_password = value;
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: kPassNullError);
          return "";
        } else if ((password != value)) {
          addError(error: kMatchPassError);
          return "";
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Confirmez le mot de passe",
        hintText: "Reconfirmez le mot de passe",
        // If  you are using latest version of flutter then lable text and hint text shown like this
        // if you r using flutter less then 1.20.* then maybe this is not working properly
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: CustomSurffixIcon(svgIcon: "assets/icons/Lock.svg"),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildPasswordFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      obscureText: true,
      onSaved: (newValue) => password = newValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: kPassNullError);
        } else if (value.length >= 8) {
          removeError(error: kShortPassError);
        }
        password = value;
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: kPassNullError);
          return "";
        } else if (value.length < 8) {
          addError(error: kShortPassError);
          return "";
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Mot de passe",
        hintText: "Saisissez votre mot de passe",
        // If  you are using latest version of flutter then lable text and hint text shown like this
        // if you r using flutter less then 1.20.* then maybe this is not working properly
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: CustomSurffixIcon(svgIcon: "assets/icons/Lock.svg"),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildEmailFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      onSaved: (newValue) => email = newValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: kEmailNullError);
        } else if (emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          removeError(error: kInvalidEmailError);
        }
        return null;
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: kEmailNullError);
          return "";
        } else if (!emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          addError(error: kInvalidEmailError);
          return "";
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Email",
        hintText: "Enter your email",
        // If  you are using latest version of flutter then lable text and hint text shown like this
        // if you r using flutter less then 1.20.* then maybe this is not working properly
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: CustomSurffixIcon(svgIcon: "assets/icons/Mail.svg"),
      ),
    );


  }

  TextFormField buildUniFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.uni,
      onSaved: (newValue) => uni = newValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: kEmailNullError);
        } else if (emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          removeError(error: kInvalidEmailError);
        }
        return null;
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: kEmailNullError);
          return "";
        } else if (!emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          addError(error: kInvalidEmailError);
          return "";
        }
        return null;
      },
    );


  }
}
```

Comment: please only add relevant code, so that we can read it faster

Comment: Where your dropdown list?

Comment: I can also bet you the farm that your "emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)" is broken, because nearly any regex people copy/paste or come up with is wrong.  Please use https://pub.dev/packages/email_validator which parses an email address *properly* according to the spec.  Unless your regex looks like this: https://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html and yes, I'm serious.

Comment: Sorry, just corrected the code.